# Web Scraping Returning Empty Brackets

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

New-ish to Python, but still self-learning online etc.

I'm trying to build a webscraper with beautifulsoup and so far into it I have found what elements on the page I want to scrape and print, but upon testing the first one it just prints empty brackets instead of the html/text on the site that I need.

Here is the code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.expireddomains.co.nz/search.php?action=search&status=6&results_per_page=100&page=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup (source.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('body > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > div.PageTabsBox > form:nth-child(4) > table.DomainList > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > a')
print(elems)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
url = 'https://www.expireddomains.co.nz/search.php?action=search&status=6&results_per_page=100&page=2'
html = req.get(url)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
table = doc.getElement('TABLE',attr='class',value='DomainList')
trs = table.TRs
for tr in trs:
  # print ([td.text for td in tr.children])
  pass
elems = trs[1].children[1].a
print(elems)
print(doc.absoluteUrl(url,elems.href))
```

Result:

```
{'href': '/register.php?domain_id=2201986', 'tag': 'a', 'html': 'academyoflearning.co.nz'}
https://www.expireddomains.co.nz/register.php?domain_id=2201986
```

You can get the examples of SimplifiedDoc [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to try out the different variations on peoples answers as well to help learn more.

Answer (score 0):

This scrapes all the links of child nodes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.expireddomains.co.nz/search.php?action=search&status=6&results_per_page=100&page=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup (source.text, 'html.parser')

Link = []
div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'PageTabsBox'})
TR = div.findAll('tr')
for tr in TR:
    TD = tr.findAll('td')

    for td in TD:
        try:
            link = td.find('a')
            link = link['href']
            Link.append(link)
        except:
            continue
print(Link)
print(Link[6])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to try out the different variations on peoples answers as well to help learn more! - I tried this version, and what it did was output a list of all the links. Unfortunately the links are not the actual URLs that are displayed on the site - they are linking to the purchase page which has a custom URL like this: /register.php?domain_id=2198181

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you are using BeautifulSoup 4.7+ which has the improved select library.

I want to answer why, what you did didn't work, and then show you how to easily make it work.

The reason your code doesn't work is for a couple of reasons. When you inspect an HTML in a browser, it can sometimes show you HTML that a parser liberally modifies to meet what it thinks your intentions are, and to give you more proper HTML. For instance, when you request the raw HTML, there are no `tbody` tags, but in a browser, it automatically inserts it as it is more proper.

`html.parser` does not insert `tbody` if not found in the raw HTML. If you wanted to see that done in BeautifulSoup, you'd need to install `html5lib` and use that parser `soup = BeautifulSoup (source.text, 'html5lib')`.

Sometimes when I run into an unexpected parser problem, I'll print out the soup object's content to a separate file so that I can analyze what is different from what I expected when I looked at it in a browser.

---

So, assuming we are still using `html.parser`, let's simplify our select and also not look for `tbody`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.expireddomains.co.nz/search.php?action=search&status=6&results_per_page=100&page=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup (source.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('table.DomainList > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > a')
print(elems)
```

Output

```
[<a href="/register.php?domain_id=2196993">absca.co.nz</a>]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. That makes sense now and I can see where I was getting it wrong!

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark one of the solutions as the accepted answer if you've figured out your issue.